# Wildcard for curl/wget to download xml feeds

Tags: curl, wildcard, wget

I want to download several feeds that are named as feed.xml, feed2.xml, feed3.xml etc. and have them appended to the same document.

My script below works, as it will check for 9 more pages (from 2 to 10). But I would like to use a wildcard instead of specifying a limit.

```
curl -lo ~/Desktop/feed.xml https://address/feed.xml && curl -s https://address/feed[2-10].xml >> ~/Desktop/feed.xml
```

The following two tries with wildcard fails for me and I am not sure what might be wrong.

With **[2-*] or ***:

```
curl -lo ~/Desktop/feed.xml https://address/feed.xml && curl -s https://address/feed[2-*].xml >> ~/Desktop/feed.xml


curl -lo ~/Desktop/feed.xml https://address/feed.xml && curl -s https://address/feed*.xml >> ~/Desktop/feed.xml
```

With **?**:

```
curl -lo ~/Desktop/feed.xml https://address/feed.xml && curl -s https://address/feed?.xml >> ~/Desktop/feed.xml
```

Source: https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_WILDCARDMATCH.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at your link about curl's wildcard match you will see that:

> This feature is only supported for FTP download.

The reason for this is simple: FTP servers are (usually) listable, so accessing `ftp://address/` will provide a list of files that can be used to resolve the wildcard in something like `ftp://address/feed*.xml`

HTTP(S) does not inherently provide a way to list all resources at an address, so curl has no way to determine how many feeds exist.

IF the server does provides a directory of feeds (at some other url), you could request that first, and use that to generate the range. Otherwise, if the number of feeds will be relatively static, you might be better of manually providing the range as you do at the moment.

Comment: Hi Ezphres,

Thanks for the answer, and it makes total sense now that you point it out. Unfortunately it doesn't provide a directory of the feeds.

I think a solution for me is to use the **--fail** flag for the pages that I want to append and I could set the number of pages to look for very high. 

     `curl -lo ~/Desktop/feed.xml https://address/feed.xml && curl --fail -s https://address/feed[2-999].xml >> ~/Desktop/feed.xml`

Do you know of any other way I could possibly do it?

Comment: If a solution with **--fail** works for you, I would probably go with that. In the interest of runtime and network hygiene, I would try to make the range as tight as possible without missing results.